# Question regarding posterior and prior distribution relation

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability

I am currently reading the book Machine Learning and Pattern regocnition by Bishop.  They state in (1) or (1.66) in the book (relating how to derive regularized SSE with posterior and prior distribution (MAP)) from Bayes theorem) that we have

(1) $p(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t}, α, β) ∝ p(\mathbf{t}|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}, β)p(w|α)$ , where $x,t,w $ are vectors

But from Bayes theorem i have $P(model|data)∝P(data|model)P(model)$ what confuses me here is how they use different parameters in the prior and likelihood. For example in the posterior $w = model$ but in the likelihood $model = t,w,β $

Maybe i just missunderstand something and a hint in the right direction would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bayes theorem you can always condition on some additional variables, for example:
$$p\left(\mathrm{model}\middle|\mathrm{data}, \mathrm{hyperparameters}\right) \propto p\left(\mathrm{data}\middle|\mathrm{model}, \mathrm{hyperparameters}\right) p\left(\mathrm{model}\middle|\mathrm{hyperparameters}\right) $$
It's actually a bit more complicated than this in Bishop's book. Bishop calls $\left\{\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t}\right\}$ the data, $\left\{\mathbf{w}, \beta\right\}$ the parameters (ie. model) and $\alpha$ the hyperparameter. So if you write the posterior out in full as:
$$ p\left(\mathbf{w}\middle|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t}, \alpha, \beta\right) \propto p\left(\mathbf{t}\middle|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}, \alpha, \beta\right)p\left(\mathbf{w}\middle|\mathbf{x}, \alpha, \beta\right) $$
then it means you are only concerned with estimating $\mathbf{w}$ and not $\beta$ (ie. you might already have some other way of estimating $\beta$).

Then what Bishop has implicitly assumed is that $\mathbf{t}$ and $\alpha$ are independent, as well as $\mathbf{w}$ being independent with $\mathbf{t}$ and $\beta$ (which are reasonable and common assumptions to make in this setting). Hence $p\left(\mathbf{t}\middle|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}, \alpha, \beta\right) = p\left(\mathbf{t}\middle|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}, \beta\right)$ and $p\left(\mathbf{w}\middle|\mathbf{x}, \alpha, \beta\right) = p\left(\mathbf{w}\middle|\alpha\right)$ so the posterior simplifies to:
$$p\left(\mathbf{w}\middle|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t}, \alpha, \beta\right) \propto p\left(\mathbf{t}\middle|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}, \beta\right)p\left(\mathbf{w}\middle|\alpha\right) $$